# Как выбрать Окно WPF, с которого будет запускаться приложение?

Tags: c#, windows, wpf

В проекте у меня есть 3 окна - LoginPage, SelecPage и MainWindow.

Так как я создал 2 первых уже после создания MainWindows, то запускается программа с MainWindow. Как мне сделать так, чтобы программа стартовала с SelectPage?

Answer (score 1):

Назначьте запускаемым Ваш SelectPage.

**Обновление**

Это можно сделать как в App.xaml, так и в настройках solution'са, если Вы, конечно, работаете в Visual Studio.

Comment: А каким способом это можно сделать?

Comment: Это можно сделать как в App.xaml, так и в настройках solution'са, если Вы, конечно, работаете в Visual Studio.